# SSRS/SQL Server access denied

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I am trying to run SSRS locally from my computer, using SQL Server 2014. In the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, I can connect to the Database I created on my own computer and my credentials checkout too. The issue is when I click on the Web Service URL and Report Manager URL, I get an access is denied error (401.2). I have went in and checked my user permissions in the SQL Server Management Studio, and I have all permissions set to where I should be able to connect and get in. To my understanding, this is not an IIS related issue, and since I am doing things locally, it shouldn't have to do with Kerberos either. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated! I have tried running IE as admin, but it still denies me with same error.

Comment: Do you get prompted for a password before the 401 or do you not even get prompted at all?

Comment: I keep thinking maybe I have rights not set correctly somewhere else in my box, but I am the admin, and I have verified that all my rights are set correctly within SQL Server. I'm on a dev computer, and am only connecting through the company Intranet, everything is done locally, so Kerberos shouldn't be affecting it. I am using my own database I created on my box, nobody else is trying to connect to it.

Comment: Is configured as Https only?

Comment: I think just http? I am not sure to be honest.

Comment: If it is out of the box install then it should allow http and https, however, the ssrs service could be changes to require https in which case you could get a transport error prior to authentication because you accessed it using http instead of https. It's one possible reason I guess.